# How to get Name of ParseUser from Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication

I'm having big problems trying to get the name of the Parse user who is signed in via Facebook.

The login works fine, I can see the user token on parse data browser, ParseUser.getCurrentUser returns a ParseUser and all, but I don't know can I get the name of the user from facebook ?

so far the code I have is

```
ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(C_RegisterLogin.this, new LogInCallback()
{
    @Override
    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err)
    {
        progressdialog.dismiss();

        if (user == null)
        {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login via Facebook failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 20);
            toast.show();
        }
        else
        {
            if (user.isNew())
            {
            }

            List args = new ArrayList<String>();
            args.add("name");
            JSONObject result = new JSONObject(ParseFacebookUtils.getSession().requestNewReadPermissions(C_RegisterLogin.this, args);
            String facebookname = result.optString("name");

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Thanks, "+facebookname+". You are now successfully logged in!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 20);
            toast.show();
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(C_RegisterLogin.this, E_SelectJourney.class));
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it, just needed it to use Request.executeMeRequestAsync from facebook , and for its session parameter, I use the session Parse gives me :D

```
if (ParseFacebookUtils.getSession().isOpened())
{
    Request.executeMeRequestAsync(ParseFacebookUtils.getSession(), new Request.GraphUserCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response)
        {
            if (user != null)
            {
                progressdialog.dismiss();
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Thanks, " + user.getName() + ". You are now successfully logged in through Facebook!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 20);
                toast.show();
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(C_RegisterLogin.this, E_SelectJourney.class));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the  Request.executeMeRequestAsync method has been depreacated so for facebook sdk 3.21 you need to use

```
   if (ParseFacebookUtils.getSession().isOpened()){
Request.newMeRequest(ParseFacebookUtils.getSession(), new Request.GraphUserCallback()
{
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response)
    {
        if (user != null)
        {
            progressdialog.dismiss();
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Thanks, " + user.getName() + ". You are now successfully logged in through Facebook!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 20);
            toast.show();
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(C_RegisterLogin.this, E_SelectJourney.class));
        }
    }
}).executeAsync();}
```